# Why does sudo su not work in my script?

Tags: command-line, scripts, sudo

I want to change ownership, group membership and access rights in a script by a sequence of commands.

Some of them need root permissions.

I first did `sudo su` in a terminal and then ran all the necessary commands once in a row. I found out that after `sudo su` all macro definitions `abc=<...>` have to be put after `sudo su`, because it seems that root does not know about macros existing in the other context.

After all my commands worked as expected, I called `histoy`, removed the line numbers and framed the relevant part of it in `sudo su` ... `exit`.

I can paste this sequence of commands into a terminal and it runs fine.

However if I prepend it with a line `#!/bin/bash` and store it as a file and make that executable, that does not work:

I get prompted for the password, but then I end up at a command line level, with the prompt ending in `#`, which shows me that `sudo su` has worked. But the rest of my command sequence has not worked.

**How can I achieve the other commands to be executed?**

Being a command line newbie, I guess I haven't understood something important yet. Please explain how to do it and why.

Comment: Don't use `sudo` inside scripts. Instead, run the entire script as root. If it's a cronjob, run it from root's crontab.

Comment: Artur, do you suggest to put `sudo -u <username>` in front of all non-privileged commands and run the whole script as `sudo xyz.sz`? This however contradicts your first advice to never use sudo within a script.

Comment: I didn't say never, I said "don't". But the one example you give would be the exception, and that could be viable in some cases. ;-)